# Save Frgament state

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity that includes two fragments, I can navigate between the frgaments by bottom navigation menu. In both of them I have a reyclerView with image and text (data is retrieving by FireBase database). 
[image]

I have the following code in MainActivity (using switch) that replaces the fragment by using navigation menu. (That is why it recreates the whole fragment every time and retrieves the data again as I found out).

```java
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_space, selectedFragment).commit();
```

I would like to save the state of each fragment (and allow user in the future manually refresh recyclerView) but so far I failed. How can I make the fragment not be recreated?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you only want to avoid the data being repeatedly loaded, you can look into the MVVM archtecture concept, see e.g. the [Guide to app architecture](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide) . There you would not store the data in the View layer but in a (custom) repository class. The Fragment would register with a lifecycle-aware  ViewModel which in turn will fetch the data from the repository.

Answer (score 0):

Use ViewPager with disabled swipe.